# Same key field different rows to separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in table where key is on multiple rows with different data but need output to one row multiple columns.

```
KEY         Unique ID   Dim     Creator        
5637145326  5637146083  Witney  david.sa
5637145326  5637144587  SE      david.sa
5637145326  5637144636  CCSE    david.sa
5637145326  5637144612  GB      david.sa
5637145326  5637152076  103608  david.sa
5637145326  5637146092  SL      david.sa
```

There are many different KEYs & Unique IDs (400,000) in the table :

Output required:

```
5637145326 Witney SE CCSE GB 103608 SL
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck (based on your sample data). Let's say there are exact duplicate `Dim` values for a new `KEY` of 5637145327. There isn't a way to guarantee that both 'Witney' values end up in the same column.

Comment: If there is a column that can identify `Dim` column uniquely, then you can `PIVOT` the data.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: you can check out STRING_AGG. But yeah, how does sql server knows in which order you want to "concat" the results, you need to have some column for that, since there's not default "order" which is stable

Comment: Man I gotta be honest... sometimes i just come here to laugh at questions :) I would be damned if I understood anything

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    [KEY] BIGINT,
    UniqueID BIGINT,
    Dim NVARCHAR(50),
    Creator NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable ([KEY], UniqueID, Dim, Creator)
VALUES
    (5637145326, 5637146083, 'Witney', 'david.sa'),
    (5637145326, 5637144587, 'SE', 'david.sa'),
    (5637145326, 5637144636, 'CCSE', 'david.sa'),
    (5637145326, 5637144612, 'GB', 'david.sa'),
    (5637145326, 5637152076, '103608', 'david.sa'),
    (5637145326, 5637146092, 'SL', 'david.sa')
```

```
SELECT 
    [KEY],
    STRING_AGG(Dim, ' ') AS ConcatenatedDims
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    [KEY]
```

| KEY | ConcatenatedDims |
| --- | --- |
| 5637145326 | Witney SE CCSE GB 103608 SL |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rRLfzBh-)

Comment: I cannot do code above for 100,000,000 rows